# Divide by zero error from Colt OpenLongObjectHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, divide-by-zero, compiler-bug, colt

I saw this exception from Colt `OpenLongObjectHashMap`:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
        at cern.colt.map.OpenLongObjectHashMap.indexOfKey(Unknown Source)
        at cern.colt.map.OpenLongObjectHashMap.get(Unknown Source)
```

It's not reproduceable.

This is indexOfKey:

```
protected int indexOfKey(long key) {
    final long tab[] = table;
    final byte stat[] = state;
    final int length = tab.length;

    final int hash = HashFunctions.hash(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    int i = hash % length;
    int decrement = hash % (length-2); // double hashing, see http://www.eece.unm.edu/faculty/heileman/hash/node4.html
    //int decrement = (hash / length) % length;
    if (decrement == 0) decrement = 1;

    // stop if we find a free slot, or if we find the key itself.
    // do skip over removed slots (yes, open addressing is like that...)
    while (stat[i] != FREE && (stat[i] == REMOVED || tab[i] != key)) {
        i -= decrement;
        //hashCollisions++;
        if (i<0) i+=length;
    }

    if (stat[i] == FREE) return -1; // not found
    return i; //found, return index where key is contained
}
```

So the only divisors used are `length` and `(length - 2)`, where `length` is `table.length`, `table` being an internal array.

However, table is only ever initialised to an array of minimum size 3 (and the default is 277 which is what I am using). Integer wrap around doesn't seem possible either.

So this would seem to be an impossible error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to reproduce it. It was an error in a log. We could try to record more data for the next time it fails, I suppose.

Comment: In my opinion, it is likely an internal bug. You could try adding and removing keys to see if there is a state where the bug occurs.

Comment: It's possible this log message happened before someone patched an error, can you check for recent changes in git as compared to the log line timestamp?
Also, I noticed this (final long tab[] = table;), what if there's some other assignment like this that is reassigning the array?

Comment: I used jad to decompile the .class file and the source looks the same as what is above. The jar file hasn't been touched in years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a Java compiler optimization error in the IBM JDK JIT compiler that was in use.

See this bug report: [IJ06000: UNEXPECTED DIVIDE BY ZERO EXCEPTION](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IJ06000)

The recommended fix is to disable the LoopVersioner optimisation on the problem methods.